# Use of FROM with Past Continuous

Tags: past-tense, continuous-aspect, prepositions

Can we use **from** when we are talking about the beginning of a period of time in Past Continuous but without indicating when that period of time stopped.

For example:

We were playing in the garden from 4 p.m. yesterday.

Comment: Certainly. Usually you would include an end point (". . . from four-thirty till six-fifteen") but it's not required. Leaving it out tends to imply that the activity continues into the present.

Comment: @Robusto: I disagree with your second sentence. If you want to say that the activity continues into the present, you have to use the present perfect continuous ("We *have been playing* in the garden"); and even then, *since* is more natural than *from*.

Comment: Yeah, I think when I said that I unconsciously had present progressive in my mind. this tends to happen with afterthoughts.

Comment: @ruakh: Do you mean that "We were playing in the garden since 4 p.m. yesterday." is correct?

Comment: @RuslanMukhanov: No, that's not what I mean; but "We had been playing in the garden since 4 PM" would be fine, if the context provides some specific later point in time when you were still playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We were playing in the garden from 4 p.m. yesterday.

Yes, that is fine. There is no *precise* indication of when the activity finished but we know it has finished.

However there is some ambiguity.

1. We were playing in the garden from (4 p.m. yesterday).  [The action is all in the past. We know that it finished before the sentence was spoken]
2. We were playing in the garden (from 4 p.m.) yesterday. [The action took place yesterday. We know it finished by midnight because that is when yesterday finished]

P.S. The ambiguity is resolved in conversation by tone of voice. In (1) there is a minor rising tone on 4 p.m. that falls on 'yesterday'.  In (2) there is a rising tone on both 4 p.m. and 'yesterday'.

Comment: Don`t you think that the progressive aspect has to be used instead ? The action started in the past and was in progress up to another point in the past.